# DNS problem maybe?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

My server (WS2k3) continues to work correctly however for some reason websites cannot be accessed via the server. Meaning if I open up Firefox on the server and navigate to google.com I receive a "server not found" error. However, if I type in the IP address http://74.125.225.51/  Google shows up.

Has anyone encountered this problem or has an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have external DNS servers configured on your WAN connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a DNS issue if you can get to Google by IP and not by name.  The first step I would take is running an `ipconfig /all` and verifying you have DNS servers set.  If you have servers set I would then run `nslookup google.com <IP of DNS server>` for each DNS server set, to see if it is responding to DNS queries.

Although, Your question / problem is on the more basic side of things.  If you are managing a server and don't know if this is a DNS problem or not... well I think you have other problems ahead of you.

Comment: Ok Thank You. it shows the windows 2003 server as the DNS server. nslookup fails and shows DNS request timed out

Comment: You'll need to investigate why DNS lookups on your DNS server are failing.

Comment: The problem is I am not exactly sure why they are failing and cant find any information in the event logs. So i tried flushing the cache and restarting the client and server DNS servers. No go so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your DNS server have Root Hints Setup, Does it have forwarders set?  You'll need to trace out each step individually to find the problem.  Client request to DNS server, DNS server to forwarders/ Root hints.

Comment: It has 2 forwarders set as well as Root hints. Ill see what I can come up with and post back here. Meanwhile any help would be great. Thanks